# Get path of where a script was called from

Tags: bash

If I have a bash script in my home directory and call for it to execute from my Desktop, is it possible for the script to know the request to execute came from the Desktop? I've figured out how to get the path of where the script file is, but I want to know where the request came from.

Thanks!

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/getting-the-source-directory-of-a-bash-script-from-within

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
srcdir=$(pwd)
```

which gets you the current directory. That is, *where* you are calling your script *from*, which should be `Desktop` something in your example.

As duly discussed in the comments, this alternative is pretty good too:

```
srcdir=$PWD
```

Comment: There is an environment variable `$PWD`

Comment: @123 you are right bro! But since OP didn't mention his OS I thought `pwd` might be a little more portable, probably doesn't matter... ;)

Comment: The environment variable `PWD` and the `pwd` command are both part of the POSIX specification; they are equally portable. Typically, you would only need to use the command if you needed to use the `-L` or `-P` options for distinguishing between a symbolic link and the directory it points to. (If anything, the *variable* is more portable, since `bash` itself will set it instead of relying on the underlying operating system to provide the command.)

Comment: @chepner Cool, thanks for the POSIX specs info... answer updated ;)